# Cannot force push even after unprotecting branches

Tags: gitlab, git-branch, git-push

I made an error pushing a wrong commit to the remote repo and want to go back to the previous commit on the remote repo, so I'm using `git push -f` to achieve this.

I selected my username below in "Allow to push" section:
[image]

[image]

Resetting locally to previous commit and then pushing it:

```
C:\Users\ul340\PRACTICE_GIT\beagle_pft_test>git reset HEAD~
C:\Users\ul340\PRACTICE_GIT\beagle_pft_test>git push -f
```

I get the following error:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Value of exclude_branches is trial dev dummy
remote: GL-HOOK-ERR: Error during Change Package Creation -
remote: GL-HOOK-ERR: ******
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To https://gitlab.com/beagle_pft_test.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/beagle_pft_test.git'
```

UPDATE:
No branches in this dropdown, even though when pushing it says I can't since it's protected.
[image]

Comment: Did you select the master branch before changing those settings? It seems no branch is selected in your Gitlab screenshot.

Comment: I'm not seeing any branches in that dropdown, I updated a screenshot.

Comment: Okay so if you are in the Maintainers group, the settings seem fine. Are you able to force push if you unprotect it? Not sure if needed here, but I also like to do a ``git fetch`` before doing anything (e.g. pushing) related to a remote branch.

Comment: I'm not able to do that unfortuantely

Comment: If all else fails, you can do a ``git revert`` on the last commit and push as usual.